# Perform merge for specific duplicate rows in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Let's be the following two DataFrames in python:

df:

| code_1 | other |
| --- | --- |
| 19001 | white |
| 19009 | blue |
| 19008 | red |

df_1:

| code_1 | code_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 19001 | 00001 |
| 19001 | 00002 |
| 19009 | 00003 |
| 19008 | 00001 |

I want to merge df with df_1:

```
    df_merge = pd.merge(df, df_1, how="left", on=['code_1'])
```

df_merge:

| code_1 | other | code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19001 | white | 00001 |
| 19001 | white | 00002 |
| 19009 | blue | 00003 |
| 19008 | red | 00004 |

I want the merge to remove duplicates in the case of code_1 and only do the merge for the first row. I could do a drop_duplicates for [other, code_1], but I would like to know if it is possible to include some parameter in the merge function to do it directly.

Expected result:

| code_1 | other | code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19001 | white | 00001 |
| 19009 | blue | 00003 |
| 19008 | red | 00004 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is no specifc parameter for [`pandas.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) that fit your needs, but you could reduce the result by dropping duplicates before merging, assumed there are only duplicates in `df_1`:

```
df_merge = df.merge(df_1.drop_duplicates('code_1'), how="left", on=['code_1'])
```